# input text in python using sage math

Tags: python, sage

Below is the code i tried using python

```
 >>> import string
 >>> def main():
    print "hey"
    print
    key = input ("key?")
    message = raw_input("Enter the message: ")
    codedMessage = ""
    for ch in message:
    codedMessage = codedMessage + chr(ord(ch) + key)
    print "the coded is: ", codedMessage


    >>> main()
    hey
    key?-1
    Enter the message: hey how are you?
    the coded is: gdx gnv `qd xnt>
```

but when i tried this in sage math..... the input function does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, while input and raw_input work from Sage in console mode, neither work from the Sage notebook (which you don't specify, but I'm assuming is what you were using).

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` *does* work in Sage Math Cloud, though with some strangeness right now (see https://github.com/sagemathinc/smc/issues/358).  It looks pretty.